# Windows Store App - XAML - Why is the Textblock is bigger the StackPanel?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have the below `XAML` and it does not do what I expect it to do.

```
<StackPanel Background="{Binding EwsColour}" Visibility="{Binding EwsVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <TextBlock Text="EWS" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="18" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="100" />
</StackPanel>
```

I end up with this

[image: Text Block Bigger then Stack Panel]

I don't understand why the `TextBlock` that has 18 in, is growing bigger then then `StackPanel`. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Share you SubheaderTextBlockStyle

Answer (score 1):

After seeing Chris W''s comment I checked the `Style` in generic.xaml.

```
<Style x:Key="SubheaderTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26.667"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
    <Setter Property="LineHeight" Value="30"/>
</Style>
```

I had no idea that there was a `LineHeight` property. Overriding it so that its the same as the font size (or bigger actually creates a better UX) stops this from happening.

```
<StackPanel Background="{Binding EwsColour}" Visibility="{Binding EwsVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <TextBlock Text="EWS" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="18" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="100" LineHeight="110" />
</StackPanel>
```